# How can i compete legally with the large firms in the below mentioned scenario?

Tags: intellectual-property

I am from India and when i did some research i found out that there are some big and well established companies in the field of windmill installation for electricity generation like Vestas India, GE Wind Energy Ltd.etc.

I have developed a product for renewable generation of electricity and want to start a startup, but it is not very complex (i.e easy to get copied) and i fear that those big companies could figure out the working of my product easily and can make a duplicate of it. Since i will be a small startup very few will recognize me and i will also be having less connections as compared to those big firms.

Also i do have an option of getting a patent done but there can be a chance that i miss some aspect and then those big firms could find any loopholes and then make my patent invalid.(I guess you must be understanding what i want to say as there is lots of possibility for a product design and it is possible that i miss some of them in my patent)

Is revealing of my product in press will be a good idea

Please guide me what should one do for the above case in order to get recognized. (i guess after update my question is making some sense)

Comment: Patenting is your best shot. A good patent lawyer can help to make sure you get as broad coverage as possible. That isn't exactly cheap but often an essential investment for a startup

Comment: Without a comprehensive patent strategy a competitor could "design around" your claims, not particularly invalidate your patents.

Comment: that is, you can get a patent *if* the idea is truly somehow novel and not actually *prior art*

Answer (score 6):

### Patent it

Hire a good patent attorney in the field and work with them to patent all patentable aspects.